# Use fswatch with imgcat

Tags: shell, fswatch

I am trying to automatically display an image in the terminal whenever a file is updated or added to a directory. I can manually do this with `imgcat` in iTerm2, and I can get `fswatch` to report correctly when a file is changed. But I can't get them to play together. I thought this would work but it reports `xargs: imgcat: No such file or directory`

```
fswatch *.png | xargs -n1 -I{} imgcat
```

Comment: Did you ever found an answer to this?  I am reading the file location from a config file, and I am getting that same error.  It only works when I hard code the file name on the script